# Better alternatives for the Sound function?

Tags: sound

The Sound function represents the  sound signal very primitive in my opinion.
There are only two buttons (play and pause). No rewind, no playing from some point on (like the most sound players have). Also the upper part(with the plots) does not "run" as the song is played. I can not change PlotStyle, PlotRange or  AspectRatio(so I can not have a good zooming). There is no ColorFunction as  the Plot function has(so I can not color the volume or pitch plots).   Not to speak of music visualization (see, for example,projectm.sourceforge.net).  Could the things get better? Any proposals, please?

Comment: @Verbeia I think the OP is more in looking for references to already done packages than to code

Comment: @Verbeia I have tried http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/how-can-i-regulate-play-sound-duration-in-mathematica-8?rq=1 
so I can regulate the duration of the sound. If you know some sample way to represent the upper part  and/or the fundamental pitch of the sound I will be very glad!